# Uploading and inserting an image using a custom option panel like in the Twenty Ten theme?

Tags: options, theme-twenty-ten

Twenty Ten gives the option to change the background image of the header.

Where is the code involved in this feature? (uploading the picture and adding the picture).

I would like to mimic this feature to archive the following:

Upload a custom logo and upload various images (maybe 10) into a slider.

So `front-page.php` would look like this:

Custom Logo:

```
<div id=logo>
   <!-- add custom logo here -->
</div>
```

Custom images for slider:

```
<div id=nivo-slider>
   <!--- add the uploaded images for the slider here -->
<div>
```

**EDIT: I realised that the theme uses this: add_custom_image_header(). Does Wordpress have a similar function to add other type of custom images (like logo, feature image, etc...) ?**

(The simpler way I found was [this](http://articles.sitepoint.com/article/wordpress-options-panel), but I think it has a bug. In order for the image to appear, I have to upload it twice).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only currently available [Theme Features](http://codex.wordpress.org/Theme_Features) of this kind are for header and background.

Sliders are very popular feature so best bet to get such functionality is look through available plugins.